# Преобразовать jsonb в integer[]

Tags: sql, postgresql

Используется PostgreSQL старше 12 версии

Имеется таблица **table**, в ней есть столбцы **item_id** и **attributes** типа jsonb. Выглядит она так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо добавить новый столбец **attributes_ids** и удалить **attributes**. Новый столбец должен содержать массив чисел, полученных путем замены json'а на значение его поля **id**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jsonb_array_elements` и `array_agg`:

```sql
select 
  item_id, 
  (select array_agg((j->>'id')::int) from jsonb_array_elements(attributes) j) ids
from _table;
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать lateral join и `jsonb_to_recordset`:

```
select item_id, array_agg(id) as attribures_id
from (
   select *, row_number() over() as rn
   from t
) as t,
lateral jsonb_to_recordset(t.attributes) as (id integer, value integer)
group by rn, item_id;
```